# How can I define Pair as a Monoid?

Tags: haskell, monoids

I have my data type `Pair` defined as

```hs
data Pair a b = Pair a b
```

I would like to make it a monoid. Here is my definition.

```hs
instance (Monoid a,Monoid b) => Monoid (Pair a b) where
    mempty = Pair mempty mempty
    mappend (Pair x1 y1) (Pair x2 y2) = Pair (mappend x1 x2) (mappend y1 y2)
```

However, I got the following error.

```
foldable.hs:3:10: error:
    • Could not deduce (Semigroup (Pair a b))
        arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
      from the context: (Monoid a, Monoid b)
        bound by the instance declaration at foldable.hs:3:10-49
    • In the instance declaration for ‘Monoid (Pair a b)’
  |
3 | instance (Monoid a,Monoid b) => Monoid (Pair a b) where
  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What went wrong?

Comment: Minor issue: the first equal sign in `mappend = (Pair x1 y1) (Pair x2 y2) = ...` should be removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mappend` is not really a method of Monoid anymore. You can implement it, but it should be just a synonym for `(<>)`, which is in Semigroup, a superclass of Monoid. To implement Monoid, you must also implement Semigroup, and put your definition of `mappend` there, named `(<>)`.

Comment: Yup. To be clear to the OP, `Monoid` *used* to stand alone, but more recently the standard library was improved by adding `Semigroup` as a superclass. This improvement, while good, unfortunately was a breaking change, so old tutorials and things might not mention this necessary bit of implementation.

Answer (score 2):

In the future `GHC.Generics` will feature a [`Generically` wrapper](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/merge_requests/5726) which allows deriving both instances [`via Generically (Pair a b)`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_via.html?highlight=derivingvia#extension-DerivingVia)

```
{-# Language DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# Language DerivingStrategies #-}
{-# Language DerivingVia #-}

import GHC.Generics

-- >> mempty @(Pair String ())
-- Pair "" ()
--
-- >> Pair "hello" () <> Pair " " undefined <> Pair "world" ()
-- Pair "hello world" ()
data Pair a b
  deriving
  stock Generic

  deriving (Semigroup, Monoid)
  via Generically (Pair a b)
```

This is already possible with [generic-data](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-data-0.9.2.0).